# Ender 3 with slic3r causes the head to go off the bed

Tags: creality-ender-3, slic3r

I just downloaded slic3r and setup my settings on it, but when I sliced and started the print, the head went off the bed and then tried to print. It doesn't matter what I set the origin to, it still does the same thing. Does someone more knowledgable with slic3r know how to fix this?

Comment: did you define the offset of the home-switch position to the corner of the bed?

Comment: Do you mean the origin?

Comment: Please post screen shots of the build plate settings. Also state printer type or bed size. You can get some more information from [this question](/q/11259).

Comment: Did you set slic3r with the correct print volume dimensions for your printer?

Comment: Yes I did, I also said it was the ender 3 (220 220 rectangle), and that it didnt matter the build plate settings, it always did the same thing no matter what settings it had